# Best way for a php class to be used inside other classes?

Tags: php, oop

Lets say I have a class called **Class_Tool_RandomColor**. All it does is return a random color. It has a Method called **getValue()**
Another is called **Class_Tool_RandomLineType**. This one returns line type as in solid, dotted and so on.. also uses a **getValue()**

Now I have many Classes that need a random color and random line type. Class_Square, Class_Circle, Class_Triangle and so on...

```
/* First I create my Class_Tool_RandomColor on top of my php file */
$colorObj = new Class_Tool_RandomColor();
$lineObj = new Class_Tool_RandomLineType();
```

...
...
...
...

```
/* Now when I created my other classes I pass the object to them */
$squareObj = new Class_Square($colorObj,$lineObj);

... ...
$circleObj = new Class_Circle($colorObj,lineObj);

... ...
```

Is this the best way? or are there other ways? 
I guess I can use extend?

```
class Class_Tool_RandomColor extends Class_Square{
```

But if I use extend, what about if multiple classes can extend it..

Comment: Asking *"Is this the best way?"* isn't a good question for SO however I would recommend composition for this. Your inheritance example won't work

Comment: better option use interface, php is not supporting multiple inheritance, to overcome that problem you need to use interface

Comment: So passing multiple classes to a parent class is not recommended? Why not?
I will read up on Interface, assuming I can find an easy to understand tutorial on it, Thanks

Comment: Inheritance shouldn't change objects type - parent is just more general type (abstract even) to its children. Your dependency injection approach is the best choice here. Interface will give you abstraction dependency (for example your Circle doesn't need to depend on random color - just something that returns color with `getValue()` method - you would achieve this by injecting different `Color`/`Line` classes). Also `Class` and `Tool` name parts are redundant - drop it. Maybe the latter is more descriptive, but i'd still use such generic name as namespace part.

Comment: I am reading about interface, but am not getting it, it's not clicking with the brain. At least not how it is applicable to my example above.

I want access to some methods of one "tool" class inside one of the other classes (circle).
The only way I can do this is by passing the $colorObj(tool)  as a param to the (circle) class.
Or by creating a new instance of the $colorObj inside the circleObj (Which I don't want to do).

Also I found this example [https://gist.github.com/reaneyk/6604607](https://gist.github.com/reaneyk/6604607) but i don't get it. I works just fine without implement

Comment: @Lixo "*So passing multiple classes to a parent class is not recommended?"* ~ nobody said that. This is exactly what I meant by composition

Answer (score 0):

If you extend a class it means that it will load at the same time when the derived class instance is created and consumes memory. You can use `extends` when you need parent class mostly in all methods of derived class. But creating instance inside class method is useful when you need minimum call from other class.
So, it depends on how much important the other class is.

Comment: also you can use getter setter for single instance of any class and share among all methods when it needed.

Answer (score 0):

I think the term you're looking for is `IoC`, Inversion of Control, but crawl before you walk and start with `Dependency Injection` and `Factories`, these are design patterns. You are treading into some much deeper water so get ready to swim.

The benefits of using a `service container` to manage classes[objects] in your application are enormous. A `service container` will *instantiate* your classes and *inject* object dependencies for you.

Some quick Google search results to get you started:

- http://coderoncode.com/dependency-injection/design-patterns/programming/php/development/2014/01/06/dependency-injection-php.html
- http://krasimirtsonev.com/blog/article/Dependency-Injection-in-PHP-example-how-to-DI-create-your-own-dependency-injection-container
- http://www.phptherightway.com/pages/Design-Patterns.html (Only the first part called *Factories* pertains to this question.
- https://github.com/domnikl/DesignPatternsPHP/tree/master/Creational (Creational php design pattern code examples)

Some Libraries:

- Pimple - A very simple DI container. http://pimple.sensiolabs.org/
- http://php-di.org/

Most of the new php frameworks include some sort of service layer implementing the stuff you read from above.